# Navigating to page with tabs and activating specific tab via navigation link

Tags: jquery, html

from index.html > use main navigation to open text.html to specific tab(tab2 or tab 3)using the appropriate navigation button

i do not want it to jump down the page, I want it to only load the page, update the highlighted tab and tab content

big thanks to adriancarriger, this works if i am on the test.html page
if i am on another page like index.html nothing works

```
nav > index.html  test.html  contact.html
                    tab1
                    tab2
                    tab3
```

code found

http://jsfiddle.net/thyt6gff/4/

script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#menu li ul a').on('click', function(e)  {

    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs 
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    //big thanks to adriancarriger, this works if i am on the test.html page
    //if i am on another page like index.html nothing works
    $('.tabs .tab-links li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-links a[href$="' + currentAttrValue + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();


    // Change/remove current tab to active
         $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});


});
```

Comment: Tried using `.load()` ?

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/wLt2se7r/5/)**

I made these changes:

1. You can navigate between top level views (Home, Test Page, and Contact).
2. All navigation classes update properly.

There are comments showing what was changed in the code below.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // **Added** - Changes top level views
    $('#menu li a').on('click', function (e) {

        var currentViewValue = jQuery(this).attr('href').slice(0, -5);

        changeView(currentViewValue);
        if (currentViewValue == 'test') {
            $('#menu a[href$="over"]').addClass('current');
        }

        e.preventDefault();

    });

    $('#menu li ul a').on('click', function (e) {

        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');


        // ** Added **
        changeView('test');
        $('#menu li ul a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        // **


        // Show/Hide Tabs 
        $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        //big thanks to adriancarriger, this works if i am on the test.html page
        //if i am on another page like index.html nothing works
        $('.tabs .tab-links li').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-links a[href$="' + currentAttrValue + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // ** Added ** => Updates main nav classes for Test Page tabs //
        $('#menu li ul a').removeClass('current');
        $('#menu li ul a[href$="' + currentAttrValue + '"]').addClass('current');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();


        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // **Added** - Dry Function to change top level views => Home, Test Page, Contact
    function changeView(currentViewValue) {
        $('#menu > li a').removeClass('current');
        $('#menu a[href$="' + currentViewValue + '.html"]').addClass('current');
        $('.content .view').hide();
        $('#' + currentViewValue).show();
    }

});
```

**Html**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <!-- ** Changed ** => Home has current class by default -->
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>

        </li>
        <!-- ** Changed ** => 
            -Removed -> Test Page does not have current class by default
            -Changed -> href points to test.html  -->
        <li> <a href="test.html">Test Page</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- ** Changed href to #over ** -->
                <li><a href="#over" class="current">Overview</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <!-- Added Home View Section -->
    <section id="index" class="view">
        <div class="tab-content">
             <h2>Home View</h2>

            <p>Home view content.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- ** Changed ** => Added id .page class and hidden by default -->
    <section id="test" class="view multilevel" style="display:none">
        <!-----tabs----->
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul class="tab-links">
                <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <!-- **Added ** => Overview section -->
                <div id="over" class="tab active">
                     <h2>Overview</h2>

                    <p>Overview text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor. Aliquam euismod at lectus non malesuada. Proin in luctus purus. Sed dictum leo vitae est gravida consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <!-- **Removed** => .active class -->
                <div id="tab1" class="tab">
                     <h2>tab 1</h2>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor. Aliquam euismod at lectus non malesuada. Proin in luctus purus. Sed dictum leo vitae est gravida consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                     <h2>tab 2</h2>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor. .</p>
                    <p>Aenean sit amet hendrerit ex, a viverra nisi. Vivamus augue neque, sollicitudin eget sem non, commodo cursus orci. Ut facilisis justo nec sapien aliquam, non malesuada tortor congue.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab3" class="tab">
                     <h2>tab 3</h2>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor.</p>
                    <p>Aenean sit amet hendrerit ex, a viverra nisi. Vivamus augue neque, sollicitudin eget sem non, commodo cursus orci. Ut facilisis justo nec sapien aliquam, non malesuada tortor congue. Vivamus mollis accumsan maximus.</p>
                    <p>Integer velit lacus, placerat sit amet ornare sit amet, mattis non mi. Nulla faucibus tristique lectus id semper. Pellentesque porta libero a tempus pretium. Integer non ex at urna convallis accumsan eu id dui.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!----/tabs----->
    </section>
    <!-- ** Added ** => Contact View -->
    <section id="contact" class="view" style="display:none">
        <div class="tab-content">
             <h2>Contact View</h2>

            <p>Contact view content.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a jquery [pushState](https://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/) implementation to do this properly. It allows you to modify the history entry of your current page. Which means, if you have 5 tabs in your page, you can use push state to modify the history entry to add selected tabs id as a parameter. Once that's done, when you reload the page, you can let it go to desired tab using adriancarrigers method.